# Show $O\left(\sqrt x\right) + \int_{\sqrt{x}}^{x}\frac{\pi(t)}{t}dt <<\frac{x}{\ln x}$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

Show the following:$$ O\left(\sqrt x\right) + \int_{\sqrt{x}}^{x}\frac{\pi(t)}{t}dt <<\frac{x}{\ln x}$$

where $\pi{(x)}$ prime counting function. This is the last step in a derivation and I'm stuck on it.

Comment: Are you allowed to use prime number theorem?

Comment: @Szeto no, this proof assumes no knowledge of the PNT

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Want
$O\left(\sqrt x\right) + \int_{\sqrt{x}}^{x}\frac{\pi(t)}{t}dt 
<<\frac{x}{\ln x}
$.

Since
$\sqrt{x}
=o(x/\ln(x))
$,
that part doesn't matter.
And, actually,
$\sqrt{x}
=o(x^{c+1/2}/\ln(x))
$
for any $c > 0$.

As for the
$\int_{\sqrt{x}}^{x}\frac{\pi(t)}{t}dt $
term,
Chebychev showed 
by elementary 
(non-complex) means that
$\dfrac78
\lt \dfrac{\pi(n)}{n/\ln(n)}
\lt \dfrac98
$,
so that
$\int_{\sqrt{x}}^{x}\frac{\pi(t)}{t}dt
\lt \int_{\sqrt{x}}^{x}\frac98\frac{t/\ln(t)}{t}dt
= \frac98\int_{\sqrt{x}}^{x}\frac{1}{\ln t}dt
$
and
$\int_{\sqrt{x}}^{x}\frac{\pi(t)}{t}dt
\gt \frac78\int_{\sqrt{x}}^{x}\frac{1}{\ln t}dt
$.

Since
$\int_c^x \dfrac{dt}{\ln(t)}
\approx \dfrac{x}{\ln(x)}+\dfrac{2x}{\ln^2(x)}+O(\dfrac{x}{\ln^3(x)})
$,
$\int_{\sqrt{x}}^x \dfrac{dt}{\ln(t)}
\approx \dfrac{x}{\ln(x)}+o(\dfrac{x}{\ln(x)})
$,
so I don't see where
the $<<$ comes from.

Comment: You did show only $\ll$, not $\sim$, by using chebyshev's estimate. To obtain $\sim$ one would use the PNT.

Comment: The $\sim$ refers only to $\int dt/\ln(t)$, nothing else.

Comment: Yep, I see. Your answer is perfectly fine (I did +1 you;) - I was only commenting on the last part of the last sentence, which I read as "I don't see where to $\ll$ in the statement comes from".

Comment: This was very helpful thank you. Instead of the $\frac{7}{8} \le \dots \le \frac{9}{8}$ I used the facts that $\ln x \pi (x) \le 2\psi (x)$ where $\psi(x)$ is the Mangoldt summatory function, as well the fact that we have $\psi(x) \le x\ln 4 + O((\ln x)^2)$, which is more in line with my context.